# SwiftのNWProtocolQUICでQUIC Streamを使いたい

Tags: swift

Swiftの Network.frameworkにあるNWProtocolQUICを使って複数のQUIC Streamを用意しそれぞれ別のデータをサーバーに送信したいです。

以下は参考にしたサイトやAppleの発表、公式のドキュメントです。これらを参考にしてコードを書いたのですが、QUICトンネルの接続はできても個々のストリームを張ってデータを送信することができません。
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10094/
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwprotocolquic
https://qiita.com/fuziki/items/5cec50ec45b188069f18
https://qiita.com/fuziki/items/93d86457afc5d72185a8#nwconnection-%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90

```
class QuicConnection {
    var acceptConnection: NWConnection?
    var openConnection: NWConnection?
    var acceptConnectionState: NWConnection.State?
    var openConnectionState: NWConnection.State?
    var receiveFromAcceptConnection: String?
    
    static func makeNWParameters() -> NWParameters {
        let options = NWProtocolQUIC.Options(alpn: ["echo"])
        options.direction = .bidirectional
        let securityProtocolOptions: sec_protocol_options_t = options.securityProtocolOptions
        sec_protocol_options_set_verify_block(securityProtocolOptions,
                                              { (_: sec_protocol_metadata_t,
                                                 _: sec_trust_t,
                                                 complete: @escaping sec_protocol_verify_complete_t) in
            complete(true)
        }, DispatchQueue.main)
        return NWParameters(quic: options)
    }

    let group: NWConnectionGroup

    init() {
        print("init")
        let parameters = Self.makeNWParameters()
        let descriptor = NWMultiplexGroup(to: .hostPort(host: "192.168.0.20", port: 4242))
        group = NWConnectionGroup(with: descriptor, using: parameters)

        //subscribe()
        group.stateUpdateHandler = { (state: NWConnectionGroup.State) in
            print("state: \(state)")
            switch state {
            case .ready:
                print("quic connected!")
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        
        group.newConnectionHandler = { [weak self] (connection: NWConnection) in
            print("new connection: \(connection)")
            self?.acceptConnection = connection
            self?.acceptConnection?.stateUpdateHandler = { [weak self] (state: NWConnection.State) in
                self?.acceptConnectionState = state
            }
            self?.subscribeAcceptConnection()
            self?.acceptConnection?.start(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        }
        
        group.start(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    }
    
    func createStream() {
        //guard let group else { return }

        let options = NWProtocolQUIC.Options()
        options.direction = .bidirectional
        let securityProtocolOptions: sec_protocol_options_t = options.securityProtocolOptions
        sec_protocol_options_set_verify_block(securityProtocolOptions,
                                              { (_: sec_protocol_metadata_t,
                                                 _: sec_trust_t,
                                                 complete: @escaping sec_protocol_verify_complete_t) in
            complete(true) // Insecure !!!
        }, DispatchQueue.main)
        openConnection = NWConnection(from: group)

        openConnectionState = openConnection?.state

        openConnection?.stateUpdateHandler = { [weak self] (state: NWConnection.State) in
            self?.openConnectionState = state
            print("state: \(state)")
            switch state {
            case .ready:
                print("stream connected!")
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                    self?.send(message: "marker1")
                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }

        openConnection?.start(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    }
    
    func send(message: String) {
        print("send start")
        let completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion = .contentProcessed { (error: Error?) in
            if let error = error {
                print("send error: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("send successful")
            }
        }
        openConnection?.send(content: message.data(using: .utf8)!,
                         contentContext: .defaultMessage,
                         isComplete: true,
                        completion: completion)
        
        print("message: \(message)")
    }
}
```

アプリが起動したら、このQuicConnectionクラスのinit関数を呼び出してインスタンスを作成し、QUICトンネルを構築します。"quic connected"のログが表示され、アプリ内で特定のアクションが動くとcreatStream関数を呼び出しストリームを張ります。"stream connected"のログが表示されるまではいいのですが、その後send関数を用いてデータを送ろうとすると”send successful"の表示がされるのですが、サーバー側にはクライアントからメッセージが届いたという出力はされません。

NQConnectionGroupを使わずNWConnectionのみの時は上手く通信できるのでサーバー側に問題はないと思います。サーバーはquic-goを用いています。

SwiftでQUICのストリームを扱ったことのある方の知識をお借りしたいです。